# Detect what answer is selected in RadioButton using Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to do a survey app using Jetpack Compose and RadioButtons.
I created a list with questions and answers

```
val surveyQuestions = listOf(
   Question("question 1", listOf("answer 1", "answer 2")),
   Question("question 2", listOf("answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3")),
   Question("question 3", listOf("answer 1", "answer 2"))
)
```

I created also a view (attachment).

[image]

How can I limit the number of answers to be selected to 1 per question?
How can I save the survey result in the form of `listOf(question1 - answer2, question2 - answer)`, etc.?

Comment: Is that the UI that u created?

Comment: It's a mock. I created something similar in the app but not exactly the same as you can see in the attachment. (work in progress) :)

Comment: ohh okay, I have done this radio button in my app like you said it can only be selected one, but in my case i have like "privacy" to let the user choose and it has only 3 radio button. but in your case it might be quite a lot, so might want to take a look at phillip's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the selection as [state](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state). It depends on your data model, for example you can use `mutableStateMapOf`:

```
val selectionStates = remember { mutableStateMapOf<Int, Int>()}

surveyQuestions.forEachIndexed { i, question ->
    question.answers.forEachIndexed { j, answer ->
        RadioButton(selected = selectionStates[i] == j, onClick = { selectionStates[i] = j })
    }
}
```

If you are using the Lazy view, you can replace `forEachIndexed` with `itemsIndexed`.

You can also move `selectionStates` from composable to [view model](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state) to make sure it is not destroyed by rotation in case you support this.

Answer (score 1):

I would store such important info inside the viewmodel as a list like

`var markedAnswers = mutableStateListOf<Int>()`

Then add an update mechanism

```
fun onAnswerUpdate(index: Int, newAnswer: Int){
 markedAnswer[index] = newAnswer
}
```

Now, just pass in this getter and setter to the Composables

```
MainActivity{
  val viewModel by viewModels<...>(()
  MyQuestionsComposable(
   answers = viewModel.markedAnswers,
   onAnswerUpdate = viewModel::onAnswerUpdate,
   ...
   )
}

@Composable
fun MyQuestionsComposable (
 questions: List<Question>, // I assume
 answers: List,
 onAnswerUpdate: (index, newAnswer) -> Unit
){
//I assume every question has three options for simplicity
/*and you must have access to the index of the question as it seems in the screenshot don't you?*/

//I'm using a loop for simplicity to gain the index, but you could do anything per your model
questions.forEachIndexed{ index, question ->
SurveyItem(
selectedAnswer = answers [index],
onAnswerUpdate = onAnswerUpdate,
options: List<...>
)
}

@Composable
fun SurveyItem(
selectedAnswer: Int,
options: List<...>,
onAnswerUpdate: (index, newAnswer) -> Unit
){
 options.forEachIndexed{index, option ->
  OptionComposable(
   modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = onAnswerUpdate(index, option)),
   selected = option == selectedAnswer
  )
 }
}
``

I'm storing selected answers as indices, and cross referencing them in the survey. Since it is mutable state, the selections will automatically update upon modification, and i have implemented this in a way that at a given time, only one answer can be selected.


I have followed Unidirectional Data Flow all over so it's best practiced. Don't worry about that.

Any doubts, just comment below.
```

Comment: By the way, as Philip pointed out, you could replace the two parameters with a map to store the index and answer in a single variable, i.e., `mutableStateMapOf` instead of `mutableStateListOf` but it depends entirely on your convenience

Comment: Works great, thanks. I'm wondering how I can check if the question has been answered?

Comment: if(selectionStates[questionIndex] != null) //selected else //unselected

Is it a good idea?

Comment: It will be either null, or 0. Just check